# How do I find the area of the region bounded by the curve and the tangent?

Tags: calculus, integration, area, tangent-line

The diagram shows a sketch of the graph of the curve $\displaystyle y=\frac{1}{4}x-x^3$ together with the tangent to the curve at the point $A(k, 0)$.

[image]

Find the area of the region bounded by the curve and the tangent, giving your answer as a fraction in its lowest terms.

---

So far,

> Equation of tangent: $y = -x/2 -1/4$
> Equation of Curve = $\frac{1}{4}x -x^3$

Coordinates of point $A=(-0.5,0)$
Coordinates of point $B=(1,-0.75)$

With that, I found the area of curve using this

> Upper limit $= 1$

> Lower limit $= -1/2$

$$\int{\frac{1}{4}x-x^3}$$
$$=[x^2/8 - x^4/4]$$
$$=-1/8 - 1/64 = 9/64$$

The solution to this question is $\frac{27}{64}$. How to solve this question?

Comment: Since you are new, I upvoted back to 0.  Typically, a question may be downvoted either because the OP didn't show work (i.e. make a reasonable attempt to solve question) or because the problem is very poorly formatted (making it difficult to decipher).  Please examine how Nikunj has edited your question to make it more readable.  ...see next comment

Comment: You're asked for the area between the cubic and the tangent. Why did you find the area between the cubic and the $x$-axis?

Comment: @Big_Smoke I think that your question **does show work.**  Anyway, rather than give you an answer, I would like to guide you thru the problem.  First of all, if the curve has equation $y = \frac{1}{4}x - x^3,$ then the equation of the derivative is $y' = \frac{1}{4} - 3x^2.$ This is the place to start.

Comment: Could you guys mind showing keyboard commands for definite and indefinite integrals as well as differentiation and possibly Vector?

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with how you guys edit the qn?

Comment: @Big_Smoke Good question.  Surrounding math jax expressions with dollar signs (i.e. \$...\$), integrals are formatted as \int or \int_a^b.  An easy way of expressing a derivative is y'.

Comment: @Big_Smoke See also https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct in that $A=(-0.5,0)$ and $B=(1,0.75)$. Given the equation of the curve is $\frac{1}{4}x-x^3$, then the equation of the tangent is $-\frac{x}{2}-\frac{1}{4}$. The integral you should evaluate should therefore be:

$$\int_{-0.5}^{1}{(\frac{1}{4}x-x^3)-(-\frac{x}{2}-\frac{1}{4})}$$
$$\int_{-0.5}^{1}{-x^3+\frac{3x}{4}}+\frac{1}{4}$$

You subtract the equation of the tangent from the equation of the curve since the tangent creates a sort of bound to the curve. Your mistake was that you only evaluated the integral of the curve, without considering what the difference evaluating between the tangent and curve would be when the bounds are different. It seems that you are completely able to evaluate these sort of integrals. Can you continue from here to arrive at $\frac{27}{64}$?

Comment: I have managed to solve the qn like what you've presented. But why for this kind of qn when the tangent is below the curve then it is subtracted and vice versa?

Comment: https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calci/areabetweencurves.aspx and https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calci/Area_Volume_Formulas.aspx are great at rigorously explaining the concept of integrating between two curves. I have referred you to these links as it provides a more general formulation and gives you a place to study other topics within calculus. I hope this helps!